# Why can't I use export default tempdata in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was using a temp data from tempdata.js to App.js but I am getting error. Please see I'm new to react native and following a tutorial. So, this is a simple todo App. I'm trying to use the temp data and unable to do that. Please help. I'm following the tutorial and still I'm getting an error. I'm using expo cl

```
export default tempData = [
    {
        name: "Plan a trip",
        color: "#24A6D9",
        todos: [
            {
                titile: "Book Flight",
                completed: false
            },
            {
                titile: "Passport Check",
                completed: true
            },
            {
                titile: "Reserve Hotel Room",
                completed: true
            },
            {
                titile: "Pack Luggage",
                completed: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Errands",
        color: "#8022D9",
        todos: [
            {
                titile: "Buy Milk",
                completed: false
            },
            {
                titile: "Plan weekend camping trip",
                completed: true
            },
            {
                titile: "Run 2 miles",
                completed: true
            },
            {
                titile: "Make a Video",
                completed: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Birthday Party",
        color: "#595BD9",
        todos: [
            {
                titile: "Get Balloons",
                completed: false
            },
            {
                titile: "Send Invitations",
                completed: true
            },
            {
                titile: "Make Dinner Reservations",
                completed: true
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Code in App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import {AntDesign} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import tempData from './tempData';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <View style={styles.divider} />
        <Text style={styles.title}>
          Todo <Text style={{ fontWeight: "300", color: "#24A6D9" }}>Listsss</Text>
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.divider} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>

      <View style={{marginVertical: 48}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addList}>
          <AntDesign name="plus" size={16} color={"#24A6D9"} />
         </TouchableOpacity>

         <Text style={styles.add}>Add List</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{height: 275, paddingLeft: 32}}>
       
          <div>
          
        <FlatList 
          data={tempData}
          keyExtractor={item => item.name}
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
            <text>{item.name}</text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
        </div>
       
      </View>
    </View>
   );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  divider: {
    backgroundColor: "#A7CBD9",
    height: 1,
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: "center"
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 38,
    fontWeight: "800",
    color: "#2D3436",
    paddingHorizontal: 64
  },
  addList: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#A7CBD9",
    borderRadius: 4,
    padding: 16,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  add: {
    color: "#24A6D9",
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: 14,
    marginTop: 8
  }
});
```

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error details as well.

Comment: I've pasted the error. I know that I can go the other way that is using useState hook easily but I am not getting why this code isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

You've got a small syntax error in the `export default` statement.

You can either do:

```
const tempData = [
  // ...
]

export default tempData
```

or

```
export default [
  // ...
]
```

Comment: ummmm. I dont know how I didn't noticed this stupid error. Thank you very much. Next time I'll try to debug the error myself before posting it on StackOverflow.